# Bootstrap - Inline forms is not displaying correctly

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a form that has 2 `text` and 1 `button` to allow user to enter searching date, and I need it to display inline. I followed using `<form class="form-inline">` but it still doesn't work. It shows like that:
[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="pull-right">
  <form class="form-inline" role="search" action="<?php echo base_url('report/searchDate')?>" method = "post">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date From" name = "searchDateFrom" size="10px; ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date To" name = "searchDateTo" size="10px; ">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default " type="submit" value = "searchDateTo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using Bootstrap 4? The markup looks like Bootstrap 3. There is no `pull-right`, `input-group-addon`, nor `btn-default` in Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0):

Use `input-daterange` class

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="input-group input-daterange">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-05">
    <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-19">
</div>
```

For more information : https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#date-range